# Is it possible to create a tag in visualforce using apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, datatable, html5

I want know if is possible to create a tag html in visualforce using APEX.
for example:

```
<table>
    <!--TR and TD will be generated by APEX-->
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just make sure your text is not being escaped:

Apex:

```
public string myTable
{
    get
    {
        return '<tr><td>Test</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<table>
    <apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!myTable}" />
</table>
```

However, I would generally recommend using an [apex:datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataTable.htm) Visualforce element instead, since it will generate the table for you based on a list, which will likely be easier to build and maintain.  Note that this will also generate a `<tbody>` element (and `<thead>` if appropriate), which may not fit your requirements:

Apex:

```
public List<String> myTable
{
    get
    {
        return new List<String>{'Test'};
    }
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!myTable}" var="element">
    <apex:column>
        <apex:outputText value="{!element}" />
    </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```